# LM358 waveform generator issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, wave, waveform, function

I would like to generate a 30 kHz & 60 kHz sawtooth waveform using an LM358P operational amplifier per the following schematic.

Theoretically, and in the simulation, the circuit should work perfectly, generating a ~30 kHz or ~60 kHz signal depending on the switch position. In reality, the signal is distorted and varies between 6 & 8 kHz respectively.

Resistors/capacitor values were calculated based on the equations from the LM741 lab exercise which I am linking below.

What can be causing the issue?

[image: Schematic]

**Falstad Simulation:** [Link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3EBs0AsBWeBOAzJRKAONNAdgJAwosgCgBDcMAJnBMRCcnLDZHKZRRw8eOBZNoYNEynZMYMAR4kpwkfRC5BPdijit2-QZDUjN0TJcxoCmSChQkmJbE12m4NAO4cuB30YmtD4KLGCYYcwcelA0AE6M4jGcgUIKnj56JjogWZr2sQkp%20dpRWmnw3okl1QJBVcXleeXBNeEs5djShTVdLM3dJpy0AOa5%20n3jJihg7LRFfpOdg6Y0AEoBmt2zJpNB49FCQdBoNADGufj%20aA7%20xyIQMFhWVoooiPgorlV5Oe-avHmlwBuiuTDQcw8o2BHAhMKYBHItE4JAotxyaAi-kEAHkAK4AFyqoXAiBMVx2PQpZJAYJi2UqCWp5MEBH2YEqYzpLI4TliGyubNpgkIRwOAjFMFOmX0f30Qta5Up5QV5xqQryCvAAFMALTkXUwDnWHAEJjmsjhFDg%20LgLEk9qkoTSWgAZU2YFuxRJ%20wAZnQADYAZ21QiYDT8nsE3sBtvNpXEEtmYZIrXjTsdybTSfYzjCcwafOTedJ9R8JeVBUptAA9uBuEIZpBUfTYFg2BDwWH65oaEA)

**LM358P Datasheet:** [Link](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf?ts=1605088888667&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DLM358PSR)

**Lab Details:** [Link](http://ee.cet.ac.in/downloads/Notes/ECLab/10-Waveform%20Generator%20Using%20OpAmp.pdf)

---

### Calculations

I haven't taken the slew rate of a device into the account initially, but here are my calculations for the 30 & 60 kHZ sawtooth generator.

#### 1. Biasing

Generator is driven from a single 24V power supply, virtual ground is derived from the voltage divider - two 1k resistors in parallel with 220nF capacitors, and saturation voltage is chosen to be 1V & 23V respectively.

**Note:** Saturation voltage was chosen without consulting the datasheet, so that was the first mistake.

[image: VCC]

[image: VGND]

[image: VSAT+]

[image: VSAT-]

#### 2. Amplitude

Chosen amplitude of a signal was 22V, so the following resistors were chosen.

[image: A]

[image: R2]

[image: R1]

#### 3. Duty Cycle

As I wanted to generate a sawtooth wave, chosen duty cycle was 10%.

[image: D]

#### 4. Frequency

To keep resistor values small, 10nF capacitor was chosen for the integrator, and for the 30kHz frequency resistor was calculated with the equation from the attached lab.

[image: F]

[image: C]

[image: R]

**Note:** The frequency had to be appropriately increased to take into the account selected duty cycle.

#### 4. Slew Rate

The slew rate of the LM358 is only 0.3 V/μ - which I didn't take into the account. For the 30 kHZ triangle wave generator minimum required slew rate is 4.14 V/μ, and for the 30kHZ sawtooth wave generator 6.9 V/μ.

[image: SR]

Comment: Are you running of 24V as in the simulation? You'd be running into slew rate limitations.

Comment: What is the slew rate required at the pin 7 output?  What is the output slew rate of an LM358?

Comment: From the datasheet: The slewrate is the rate at which an operational amplifier can change its output when there is a change on the input.These devices have a 0.5-V/μs slewrate (B Version).

You are right, running the circuit from the 12V power supply generates a 6-8 kHz signal, while from the 24V power supply the signal is 3-4 kHz.

Comment: What the schematic doesn't show is the hidden connections.   If you built this with long dangly wires on a plugboard, it's probably the implementation, not the circuit, that's at fault.  "neatness counts" when building circuits.    Another thing that's not shown on the schematic is the electrical load of "sweep".   Figure out the input impedance of "sweep" and add that to your simulation.  Does it still work???

Comment: And, almost certainly, you should have capacitors on the power supply pins of the opamp.  Those are not shown here.  If you don't have such things, the opamp could definitely behave oddly (in a manner the simulation doesn't simulate).

Comment: @George There are a lot of things going on here. First off, the LM358 has both input range and output range limitations. Second, your schematic taken from the lab sheet uses a bipolar supply. Yours is single-rail. Choices in your resistors will also affect the required output range, which itself may run up against datasheet limitations. And the frequency varies with the setting of the (+) input's value with respect to the rails, besides all of that. I'd like to see your calculations -- most especially the peak-to-peak output calc and how it compares with the datasheet output & input limits.

Comment: @George You and others have mentioned slew rates. At worst-case 60 kHz and, let's say, 10%/90% sawtooth setting, you'd only have about \$1.7\:\mu\text{s}\$ to slew across the required peak-to-peak range. That's not a lot of time for this device. From your own figure for the B version, that's less than \$1\:\text{V}_\text{PP}\$ total. You'd have to design for that by reducing the output range with your resistor ratios if you want to reach 10%/90%, for example. There are a lot of details to check. May I assume you are stuck with the LM358?

Comment: This is not a complete circuit. Please show what 'vgnd' and 'boost' are connected to. What is the power supply voltage?

Comment: I apologize for not responding sooner! Label "BOOST" is connected to the 24V Power Supply, and label "VGND" to the voltage divider consisting of two 1k resistors in parallel with 220nF capacitors. I was stuck with the LM358, but will be getting an op-amp with a better slew rate - LM833N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your resistor values are too low. Try about 10x the given values and reduce the capacitor proportionally to compensate.
2. R34 is too low in relation to R36. The op-amp does not swing to the power supply rails.
3. The op-amp you've chosen is not fast enough for the integrator function, let alone to be used as a comparator at tens of kHz. Note that many op-amps perform badly as comparators, and as well may present a very low impedance to differential voltages of greater than a diode drop or two.

Here is what it looks like operating, albeit at ~1/100 of your desired frequency:

[image]

With 10K/15K/5.2K/100nF